# Migrate Azure VM (Oracle) to AWS RDS Aurora

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, azure, rds, amazon-aurora

We need to migrate an Oracle DB from Azure VM to AWS RDS Aurora. And we have a checklist that what are the things we have to take care while doing migration from Oracle to Aurora.

But, what would be the best approach to do the migration. i.e., Migrate Azure Oracle VM to AWS EC2 and then, migrate to RDS. Or Migrate directly from Azure VM to AWS RDS Aurora using any Azure service(s), DMS, Datapump, SCT, something like that.

(I am not familiar with Azure DMS / DB related services)

Answer (score 0):

I would go direct from Azure Oracle RM to the AWS RDS.

For the tool take a look at using the AWS Database Migration Service (DMS).  It lets you connect to your source database (Azure Oracle) to your target database (AWS RDS For Oracle).  AWS DMS handles creating the schema and tables in the target database.

The DMS deploys on dedicated VMs for you migration and is priced based on the size of the EC2 instance you will need from a t2.micro ($0.43/day) to a r4.8xlarge ($80/day + storage cost) and everything in between Data transfer into DMS is free and transfer to an RDS in the same AZ (availability zone) as the DMS is free.

A few features that makes the DMS nice include:

Continuous Data Replication: Once your initial migration is completed it can continue to replicate the data until you are ready to make the switch.  This is nice because you do your migration ahead of time and have plenty of time for verification before you switch the application over.

Schema Conversion Tool: Not useful in your case but if you where migrating from to a different database such as Oracle to Aurora it would handle the schema for you.

You can learn more and get start at [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/)